# Dynamically fitting two straight lines and getting the crossing point between those lines in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, lm

I am having a spectral reflectance data like

```
library(hsdar)
library(tidyverse)

##Create some data
parameter <- data.frame(N = seq(1, 1.5, 0.05), LAI = seq(1,6,0.5))
spec <- PROSAIL(parameterList=parameter)
```

Then I have calculated the 1st order derivative of the data like

```
d1 <- derivative.speclib(spec)
```

I have extracted the dataframe from d1 object using following code

```
d1_df <- d1@spectra@spectra_ma
d1_wav <- d1@wavelength
colnames(d1_df) <- d1_wav
#Plotting of the data
matplot(d1_wav,t(d1_df[1:11,]),type='l', xlim = c(660, 800), ylim=c(-0.01,+0.01), xlab='Wavelength /nm',ylab='Reflectance')
```

[image]

Then I subsetted far-red (680 to 700 nm) and NIR (725 to 760 nm) region like

```
d1_df %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(paste0("WV_", names(.))) %>% 
  mutate(ID = seq.int(nrow(.))) %>%
  select(281:301, ID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
  separate(name, c("chr", "wv"), convert = T)

d1_df %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(paste0("WV_", names(.))) %>% 
  mutate(ID = seq.int(nrow(.))) %>%
  select(326:361, ID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
  separate(name, c("chr", "wv"), convert = T)
```

Now how can I fit two straight lines for the two regions and get the x corrosponding to the intersection of these two straight lines for each ID as shown in the following figure?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a single unique answer to this question, because there is not a unique reflectance line (each ID has its own reflectance line and therefore its own unique crossing point). If we take your subsetted data like this:

```r
region_A <- d1_df %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(paste0("WV_", names(.))) %>% 
  mutate(ID = seq.int(nrow(.))) %>%
  select(290:301, ID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
  separate(name, c("chr", "wv"), convert = T) %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(ID))

region_B <- d1_df %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(paste0("WV_", names(.))) %>% 
  mutate(ID = seq.int(nrow(.))) %>%
  select(332:350, ID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
  separate(name, c("chr", "wv"), convert = T) %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(ID))
```

and plot it, we see:

```
p <- ggplot(region_A, aes(x = wv, y = value, group = ID)) + 
      geom_line() +
      geom_line(data = region_B) 
p
```

[image]

If we extrapolate these lines, we can see they cross at different wavelengths:

```r
p <- p + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, fullrange = TRUE, 
                     aes(colour = factor(ID)), se = FALSE) +
         geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, fullrange = TRUE, 
                     data = region_B, aes(colour = factor(ID)), se = FALSE) +
         coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.0125))
p
```

[image]

We can get a linear regression on each of these lines like this:

```
modA <- lm(value ~ wv * ID, data = region_A)
modB <- lm(value ~ wv * ID, data = region_B)
```

And we can define a function that returns 0 when the prediction from both models at a particular wavelength is the same like so:

```r
meet_at <- function(X, ID)
{
  A <- predict(modA, newdata = list(wv = X, ID = ID))
  B <- predict(modB, newdata = list(wv = X, ID = ID))
  abs(A - B)
}
```

This allows us to use the `optimise` function to find the crossing point for each of the two lines and return a nice data frame of results as follows:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(region_A$ID), function(i) {
  wv <- optimize(meet_at, c(700, 740), ID = i)$minimum
  value <- predict(modA, newdata = list(wv = wv, ID = i))
  data.frame(wv, value, ID = as.character(i))
}))

df
#>           wv       value ID
#> 1   708.8861 0.004254394  1
#> 11  710.4923 0.005915650  2
#> 12  712.1372 0.007343448  3
#> 13  713.6095 0.008527553  4
#> 14  714.8414 0.009483770  5
#> 15  715.8220 0.010241372  6
#> 16  716.5676 0.010833544  7
#> 17  717.1078 0.011292029  8
#> 18  717.4764 0.011644701  9
#> 19  717.7071 0.011914912 10
#> 110 717.8309 0.012121712 11
```

and we know these results are correct if we draw these points on our plot:

```
p + geom_vline(data = df, aes(xintercept = wv, colour = ID)) + 
    geom_point(data = df)
```

[image]

So the answer to your question is that the crossing occurs according to the `ID` at wavelengths ranging between 708 and 718 nm, with the exact details as per `df`

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Yes, the crossing points will be different for every sample. I will give it a try and get back to you.